# JPopup Menu Does not show up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, popup

[image]

The idea is to create a `JPopupMenu` that will show up right underneath the exclamation mark when I `LEFT CLICK` on it.
I am not using the `isPopupTrigger()` method as I have created a separate `MouseInputHandler`to implement my specific condition.
However the `JPopupMenu` does not show up.
Here is the code:

```
protected class LabelHandler extends MouseInputAdapter{


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        JLabel cause = (JLabel) e.getSource();
        if(cause == saveLabel){
            try{
                desktop.open(f);
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(cause == downLabel){

            popup.show(ScreenRecorder.this, e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        JLabel cause = (JLabel) e.getSource();
        if(cause == saveLabel){
            saveLabel.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }else if(cause == downLabel){
            downLabel.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        JLabel cause = (JLabel) e.getSource();
        if(cause == saveLabel || cause == saveLabel){
            saveLabel.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }else if(cause == downLabel){
            downLabel.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }
    }
}
```

The label is named `downLabel` cause it was supposed to be an arrow pointing downwards but anyways, I put an exclamation there. Please tell me why the JPopupMenu does not show up. Yes, I set up the menu in another method.

### EDIT:

#### Code for creating the JPopup:

```
public void setupJPopup(){
        encodingGroup.add(avi);
        encodingGroup.add(quicktime);

        popup.add(avi);
        popup.add(quicktime);
        popup.addSeparator();

        recordingAreaGroup.add(entireScreen);
        recordingAreaGroup.add(custom);

        popup.add(entireScreen);
        popup.add(custom);
        popup.addSeparator();

        cursorGroup.add(selectBlackCursor);
        cursorGroup.add(selectWhiteCursor);
        cursorGroup.add(selectNoCursor);

        selectCursor.add(selectBlackCursor);
        selectCursor.add(selectWhiteCursor);
        selectCursor.add(selectNoCursor);

        popup.add(selectCursor);
        popup.pack();
    }
```

*Variables involved in the above code are:*

```
/* Creating the JPopupMenu containing the various menu items */
    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();

    ButtonGroup encodingGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup recordingAreaGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup cursorGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    /* Handler for labels*/
    LabelHandler labelHandler = new LabelHandler();

    JRadioButtonMenuItem avi = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("AVI",true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem quicktime = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("QuickTime",false);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem entireScreen = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Entire Screen",true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem custom = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Custom...",false);
    JMenu selectCursor = new JMenu("Select a cursor");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selectWhiteCursor = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("White Cursor",true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selectBlackCursor = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Black Cursor",false);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selectNoCursor = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("No Cursor",false);
/* Icons for the cursors */
    Icon blackCursor = (Icon) new ImageIcon("src/images/blackCursor.png");
    Icon whiteCursor = (Icon) new ImageIcon("src/images/whiteCursor.png");
```

Comment: can you post sample working code with that issue to try?

Comment: My bet is that you forgot to add your `LabelHandler` as a `MouseListener` of the `JLabel downLabel`. Do you have somewhere in your code a line like this: `downLabel.addMouseListener(labelHandler);`? Hard to tell without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet do I need that? I guess there is no need because if someone clicks the exclamation mark, LEFT CLICK, the menu must show up. Anywhere else, no it must not whether it be right click or left click. What I will do is I will link you guys to complete source code in my GDrive if thats fine

Comment: _Do I need that?_ Of course you need that, otherwise your mouselistener is not attached to any component(s) and will never receive any events. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I tried that. Did not work! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you Post the relevant code for `popup`.

Or better a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

I canot reproduce your problem.

---

You should use

```
saveLabel.equals(cause)
```

insread  of

```
cause == saveLabel
```

Comment: does `JLabel` overrides `equals()` method?

Comment: Not necessary because `==` will be comparing addresses. `saveLabel` has been instantiated early on so its address won't change. And `==` works well when it comes to changing the cursors from `DEFAULT_CURSOR` to `HAND_CURSOR`, I don't know what is wrong with `JPopupMenu` :-)

Comment: @vishal_aim No, it does not.

Comment: @Little Child again post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, otherwise everything here are shots to the dark only

Comment: `JLabel saveLabel = new JLabel("<html><body style='align: center;'><u>Videos</u>");`
 `JLabel downLabel = new JLabel(downIcon,JLabel.RIGHT);`

Comment: I tried the best I could but I guess I cant post the working code cause everything gets messed up. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This example work for me.  I was seeing your problem for a while - then I realized I never called the `setupJPopup()` method - maybe that's your problem as well?  Otherwise, can you start adding things from your code to this example until you recreate the problem?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PopupMenu extends Box{

    Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(400,30);

    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();

    ButtonGroup encodingGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup recordingAreaGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup cursorGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    JRadioButtonMenuItem avi = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("AVI",true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem quicktime = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("QuickTime",false);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem entireScreen = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Entire Screen",true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem custom = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Custom...",false);
    JMenu selectCursor = new JMenu("Select a cursor");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selectWhiteCursor = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("White Cursor",true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selectBlackCursor = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Black Cursor",false);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selectNoCursor = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("No Cursor",false);
    //Icons for the cursors 
    Icon blackCursor = (Icon) new ImageIcon("src/images/blackCursor.png");
    Icon whiteCursor = (Icon) new ImageIcon("src/images/whiteCursor.png");

    public PopupMenu(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        // The part I was missing and was throwing me for a loop
        // Maybe you're not calling this method, and therefore not setting up the popup menu???
        setupJPopup();

        //Other normal stuff
        JLabel clickMe = new JLabel("ClickMe");
        clickMe.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        clickMe.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }});

        add(clickMe);       
    }

    public void setupJPopup(){
        encodingGroup.add(avi);
        encodingGroup.add(quicktime);

        popup.add(avi);
        popup.add(quicktime);
        popup.addSeparator();

        recordingAreaGroup.add(entireScreen);
        recordingAreaGroup.add(custom);

        popup.add(entireScreen);
        popup.add(custom);
        popup.addSeparator();

        cursorGroup.add(selectBlackCursor);
        cursorGroup.add(selectWhiteCursor);
        cursorGroup.add(selectNoCursor);

        selectCursor.add(selectBlackCursor);
        selectCursor.add(selectWhiteCursor);
        selectCursor.add(selectNoCursor);

        popup.add(selectCursor);
        popup.pack();
    }  


    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return preferredSize;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new PopupMenu());
        frame.validate();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```